# Terminal Just Likes Bash? [OSX]

Tags: macos, terminal

I set my terminal to open using zsh instead of bash, and it works for a week or so, and then it switches back to bash. Any idea of why this might be happening?

I'd really prefer to keep the change at the terminal level, and not actually switch my system shell.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning this is about Mac OS X outside of the tags as well.

Comment: @oKtosiTe done.

Answer (score 4):

Run the command chsh. I did this and my zsh sticks on Snow Leopard.

Comment: Likewise. I used chsh to switch to zsh under Leopard, and it's stuck ever since.

Answer (score 2):

How did you change your shell?

This works for me:

1. Go to System Preferences.
2. Open the Accounts prefpane.
3. Authenticate so you can make changes.
4. Control- or right-click on the name of your account and select Advanced Options.
5. Under Login shell, select or enter the path to your `zsh`. (Note: I think this shell will also have to be listed in `/etc/shells`.)

You can also change it in Terminal itself:

1. Open up the Terminal preferences.
2. On the Startup tab, under Shells open with, Select Command (complete path) and enter the path to the shell.

Comment: I think firs way is actually working as `chsh`

Comment: Sorry the question wasn't clear. I do #2. After a week or so, it switches back.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using MobileMe?  At least for me, I have all kinds of problems with preference syncing.  I can change a setting on my laptop and a couple days later it gets set back to the old setting (probably because my desktop is always running while my laptop is not).

It just strikes me as odd since mobileme is the only thing I've seen cause preference reset issues like this...

Answer (score 0):

Some terminal programs allow you to run a program on login. Try running bash?

Comment: You must mean zsh... :-)

Answer (score 0):

How did you change it to zsh?

I briefly ran osx (not for very long, but longer than a few weeks) and just used chsh to change it to zsh and then the job was done. Do you have automatic updates running?